# How to remove unwanted row value from sql table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a strange question. I have been added some unwanted value into my company sql db. how to delete from my sql table.

```
columnA   ColumnB   ColumnC   ColumnD   ColumnE 
   1         22      3332
   2         11      5543
   3         11      4444
   4         11      1234
   4         11      1344
   4         11      5666
```

it must be

```
columnA   ColumnB   ColumnC  ColumnD   ColumnE 
   1        22       3332
   2        11       5543
   3        11       4444
   4        11       1234
```

Comment: What's the criteria for which row to keep?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **P L E A S E** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! THen you don't need any of those messy `&nbsp;` and `<br>` tags, either!

Comment: @marc_s, he has 748 reputation and have 160 questions already. Not a new user.

Comment: @kaf: even more troubling he's not yet discovered how to format sample data .....

Comment: Yeah, I just checked, 160 questions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER` function

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT columnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, ColumnE,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY columnA, ColumnB ORDER BY ColumnC)
   FROM dbo.TableName
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

This issumes that duplicates are determined by the first two columns and that you want to keep that with the lowest `ColumnC` value as in your sample.

Here's a [**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9b83/5/2).

Comment: This is the way I thought at first as well. However, this expects that duplicates are *always* entered with higher columnC values (as he shown in data examples.)

Comment: @Kaf: I have no idea (since OP hasn't told us) what he wants to delete, this is just what we could take from the little sample he has provided. But i think that he knows how to adjust the query once he has understood how it works.

Answer (score 4):

So you're looking to delete the last two rows? Just create delete statements which match the criteria of those you want to get rid of (as it looks like you haven't duplicated any existing data):

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE ColumnA = 4 
AND ColumnB = 11 
AND ColumnC = 1344

DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE ColumnA = 4 
AND ColumnB = 11 
AND ColumnC = 5666
```

(Of course replacing "MyTable" with the actual name of your table, which you haven't supplied).

Answer (score 1):

Because we don't know which records you want to keep, it's hard to answer your question.  If you want to keep the first record grouped by your first 2 columns, then this will be close -- although not guaranteed:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1,col2 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
FROM YourTable
  ) 
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN<>1
```

If you have another field (such as in Tim Schmelter's answer), then use that instead of SELECT NULL.

Here is a Fiddle showing what will remain: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29aec/4